# How to enable OAuth2 on a single endpoint with Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application (spring-boot-starter-parent 3.1.5) that exposes REST endpoints with different security needs.

Some endpoints will accept a session cookie, others will accept a JWT signed by my own server. I have a requirement to add an endpoint that will accept a JWT from an authentication server, so I chose to use the Auth0 library that integrates with Spring Boot so that I get the benefits of discovery of the authentication server's signing keys and validation of the JWT.

Following [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security5), I end up with the following configuration:

```java
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authManager) throws Exception {
        return http
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .logout(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.requestMatchers("/login").permitAll())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.requestMatchers(getRequestMatchers()).authenticated())
                .addFilterBefore(getCustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authManager), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.requestMatchers("/sso/login").authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(withDefaults()))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll())
                .build();
    }
```

Where what got added to support this new endpoint ("/sso/login") was:

```java
.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.requestMatchers("/sso/login").authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(withDefaults()))
```

The idea is that the request matchers that get returned from `getRequestMatchers()` should go through my CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter, and the single "/sso/login" endpoint would be the only endpoint that I need the oauth2ResourceServer functionality for. It's worth noting that I explicitly exclude the "/sso/login" endpoint in the matcher returned from `getRequestMatchers()`. However, I've only been able to configure this filter chain such that any request will start with the BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter (so it's being treated like a resource server endpoint), and if that fails (because it is using the session cookie or a JWT signed by my server), then the entire chain is aborted and it doesn't attempt to authenticate using the CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter.

Open to ideas on how to separate out this configuration to make it work.

Comment: Have you tried defining [multiple `SecurityFilterChain` beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity_instances) with `@Order`?

Comment: This was exactly the piece I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation linked by Steve Riesenberg was what helped here, and was the piece I was missing despite having read the architecture of Spring Security and how filters work. Here's an example of what it could look like:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain oauth2FilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .logout(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .securityMatcher("/api/sso/login")
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(withDefaults()))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain customAuthFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authManager) throws Exception {
        return http
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .logout(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .securityMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.requestMatchers("/api/login").permitAll())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.requestMatchers(getRequestMatchers()).authenticated())
                .addFilterBefore(getCustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authManager), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll())
                .build();
    }
}
```